# How do I measure how much data a given process is using in real time?

Tags: windows-10

I'm going to be moving soon and I'm trying to figure out exactly what upload/download speeds I need. Is there any way to measure how much data a given program (or my computer as a whole) is transmitting in real time? Looking online most information I've found is about how to measure monthly data usage, which is a separate matter.

Comment: Most ISP packages are not that close.   Get an average size plan and that should work. If you are on an Insider Program you may need a bigger plan

Answer (score 0):

There are free network monitor applications such as [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/),  [NetTraffic](https://www.venea.net/web/nettraffic), and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/nettraffic/), that can show network usage with fine granularity, and summarize usage as well.

Try using your favorite apps and calculate how much bandwidth they need.

Otherwise, you'd be getting someone's opinion, not facts.